# RecyclerView Notify adapter when data changed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**Explication:**

i'm trying to build file manager app with camera
when i take picture and display it into my recycleview it's ok but when i delete any picture and try to take picture again the recyclerview display old pictures and when i check the path all are new pictures
i tried notifychanged notifyremoved and i tried to refrech data get data from path but nothing is working

**i'll comment all thing i tried in the code**

**adapter class**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<File> filesAndFolders;
    RecycleAction recycleAction;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> filesAndFolders,RecycleAction recycleAction){
        this.context = context;
        this.filesAndFolders = filesAndFolders;
        this.recycleAction = recycleAction;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycle_gird_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view,recycleAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        File selectedFile = filesAndFolders.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(selectedFile.getName());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
        ImageFileFilter img = new ImageFileFilter();
        if (img.accept(selectedFile)) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((AppCompatActivity) context ).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load(selectedFile).placeholder(R.drawable.border).into(holder.imageView);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

        } else {
            if (selectedFile.isDirectory()) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
            }  else {
                // This is not an image file.
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_insert_drive_file_24);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filesAndFolders.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView,RecycleAction recycleAction) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name_gird);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_view_gird);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(v->{
                recycleAction.onClick(itemView,getAdapterPosition());
            });
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(v->{
                recycleAction.onLongClick(itemView , getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            });
        }

    }


}
```

**onLongClickListener**

```
   @Override
public void onLongClick(View item,int position) {
    File selectedFile = filesAndFolders.get(position);
    ImageView img = item.findViewById(R.id.icon_view_gird);
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,item);
            popupMenu.getMenu().add("DELETE");
            popupMenu.getMenu().add("SHARE");
            popupMenu.getMenu().add("RENAME");

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    
                    
                    
                    //the problem is here 
                    
                    if(item.getTitle().equals("DELETE")){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"DELETED ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            item.setVisible(false);
                            selectedFile.delete();
                           adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                          //  RefreshData(path,filesAndFolders);
                          // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          //adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                        
                        //this what i tried and finelly refresh activity
                        
                            startActivity(getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    if(item.getTitle().equals("SHARE")){
                        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable=(BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
                        Bitmap bit = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                       shareImageandText(bit,selectedFile);
                    }
                    if(item.getTitle().equals("RENAME")){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"RENAME ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popupMenu.show();
        }
```

**RefreshData Method**

```
private void RefreshData(String path, ArrayList<File> filesAndFolders){
        filesAndFolders.clear();
        if(path==null){
            File root = new File(DIRICTORY);
            ArrayList<File> diractorus = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(root.listFiles()));
            ArrayList<File> diractorus_new = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<File> imagesss =new ArrayList<>();
            for (File item:diractorus) {
                if (item.isDirectory()) {
                    diractorus_new.add(item);
                }else{
                    imagesss.add(item);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(imagesss);
            Collections.sort(diractorus_new);

            diractorus_new.addAll(imagesss);
            filesAndFolders.addAll(diractorus_new);
        }else {
            File root = new File(path);
            ArrayList<File> diractorus = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(root.listFiles()));
            ArrayList<File> diractorus_new = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<File> imagesss =new ArrayList<>();
            for (File item:diractorus) {
                if (item.isDirectory()) {
                    diractorus_new.add(item);
                }else{
                    imagesss.add(item);
                }
            }

            filesAndFolders.addAll(diractorus_new);
            filesAndFolders.addAll(imagesss);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Not direct related, but you do not need to call Glide from a separate thread - it handles that internally already.

Comment: @TylerV When the picture take Time to load that's make all app crash that's why i make it in seperate thread
The problem is not on thé thread i tried to remove it even it's crashing just to test but nothing changee

Comment: Glide handles loading from a separate thread already - if the app was crashing it was from some other reason. If it's crashing you should include the stack trace from the logcat in your question too.

Comment: @TylerV your right bro i was using Picasso now there is no crash i test it with Glid thnx 

Comment: @TylerV can you help me bro i find the problem the problem is on Glide librery when i tried picasso  `Picasso.get().load(Uri.fromFile(selectedFile)).into(holder.imageView);` or `holder.imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(selectedFile));` it's work but there is a lag in ui even when i use `((AppCompatActivity)context).runOnUiThread`

Comment: You do not need to create a Thread yourself or do anything involving `runOnUiThread`. If by "there is a lag" you mean it takes a moment to load the images, that is expected. When you call Glide or Picasso they launch a background thread to load the image and display it when it's loaded. This takes some time, since images can be large, so there will always be a slight loading lag.

Comment: @TylerV no it's lag the whole UI i have in may main activity (FAB) with some animation it's laging
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kj1HENIgQWdPR3JHjxfzgjgtpFvs3eB-/view?usp=drivesdk )

Comment: @TylerV this video explain watch i mean thnx for your help

Comment: I don't see any lag in that video - but more to the point, you need to ask a complete, reproducible, well-explained question here. StackOverflow is a Q&A repository, not an online debugging service.

Comment: @TylerV ok thnx